# Get rid of eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars error when index is not used in map function typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint, map-function

I got this code:

```
const reducer = (element:number, index: number) => [element]; //es lint error.
const positionsArray = $.map(this.positions, reducer);
```

I am casting a Float32Array (it is this.positions) to a js array.
I get the error:
'index' is defined but never used.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

I cannot apply the "// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars" (which btw I dont think is a pleasant solution)

How to get rid of this error for this case that I don't need the index? I checked reduce and try to retrieve the accumulator but did not achieve it.
Thanks.

EDIT:
If I dont define the index I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, is `this.positions` the Float32Array and `$` jQuery?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Thanks for asking, because that should have been clear in the question

Comment: Obviously you shouldn't, in principle, have to change logically correct code to satisfy the type checker but why would you use the jQuery map when there's one that array itself provides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define the parameter. Neither TypeScript nor JavaScript requires you to use all parameters that a callback might accept.

You can also convert the typed array to a normal array by invoking the iterator - it looks like jQuery's `.map` doesn't behave well with it, so use plain JS instead:

```
const positionsArray = [...this.positions].map(element => [element]);
```

If you just want to get a plain array from the typed array, don't use `.map`, just invoke the iterator alone:

```
const positionsArray = [...this.positions];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried that out, but obtain an error if dont define the index. See updated question

Comment: That returns a 2 dimensional array (number[][]). I would like to obtain a number[] with the float32Array components. On the other hand, Neither TypeScript nor JavaScript requires you to use all parameters, but if you have the eslint configuration to avoid unused vars, and want to keep using that, is ESLint demand then. My point is that I would not like to remove that linting option, even if Javascript and typescript would not complain.

Comment: If you just want to turn the typed array into a normal array and nothing else, then the `.map` doesn't really make sense - just call the typed array's iterator.

Comment: [...this.positions] is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot